# find correlation between runoff station and the corresponding SPI1,SPI3,SPI6 for the station

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help finding the correlation between my plots. In the code below, I first calculated the runoff for a station in Norway. Then I calculated SPI1, SPI3 and SPI6 for the drive.
I further wish to find the correlation the run-off station has with relative SPI1, SPI3 and SPI6

Is it possible to get one plot that shows both runoff, SPI1-3-6?

from pandas import read_csv

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os

import cartopy

from datetime import date,datetime

import datetime as dt

## timeserie of July-water flow at stasjon 200011

dir1 = "/Users/mad/Desktop/mystations/"

files = os.listdir(dir1)

files = np.sort(files)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.txt_')]

df = pd.read_csv(dir1+files_txt[0], skiprows=6, header=None, index_col=0,sep=" ",names = ["Year","Runoff"], na_values=-9999)

list(df.columns)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H%M")

pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H").min()

pd.to_datetime(df.index,format="%Y%m%d/%H").max()

parse_dates=True

myperiod = df["1985":"2018"]

df = myperiod.resample("m").mean()

july = df[df.index.month == 7]

plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))

plt.plot(July)

plt.title("Time series")

plt.ylabel("runoff [mm/day]")

plt.xlabel("year")

plt.show()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7vpK.png)

## timeserie of july-SPI 1 to the same station

spi1= pd.read_csv('SPI1_and_rr_for_200011.0.csv',header=0 , na_values=-9999)

spi1.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%Y-%m-%d')

a = spi1[spi1.index.month == 7]
a.plot(y='spi',figsize=(16,4))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFU4R.png)

## timeserie of july-SPI 3 to the same station

spi3 = pd.read_csv('SPI3_and_rr_for_200011.0.csv',header=0,parse_dates=True)

spi3.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')

b = spi3[spi3.index.month == 7]

b.plot(y='spi',figsize=(16,4))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omhXw.png)

## timeserie of july-SPI 6 to the same station

spi6 = pd.read_csv('SPI6_and_rr_for_200011.0.csv',header=0,parse_dates=True)

spi6.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')

c = spi6[spi6.index.month == 7]

c.plot(y='spi',figsize=(16,4))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDhBb.png)